# Change the mapping of a field in Kibana from String to Double

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, logstash, spark-streaming, kibana

I am capturing live streaming of data and processing it.   I configured my `logstash.conf` file.

I started my ElasticSearch, Logstash and Kibana.

I created my index in kibana and when I do a `get index` in the dev tools,

I have something like this

```
    "message": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
```

I want to change the type of message from String to Double. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change mapping after an index is created - you'll have to create the mapping yourself in a new index explicitly create the fields/types you need:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

then re-index from the old to the new index:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Note the type you want is 'double' not 'Double':
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Changing the data type of a field in Elasticsearch(ES) is a breaking change. In your case, you need an update the mapping and update in ES.

Please use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html to verify, that mapping is updated successfully in ES.

Reindex API requires `_source` to be enabled, Please refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html for more information on `_source` field and whether it's enabled in your case.

If it's not enabled in your case, then the only option you have it to delete the old index(which has older mapping) and create it again with the new mapping.

Let me know if you have any doubt or face any issue implementing this.

Comment: I created a new index and used the `filter-mutate` functionality on the data I got from ElasticSearch. It worked.